# Macro is only printing in active worksheet opposed to the referenced sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a VBA Macro that tries to take values input from text boxes in a user form and copies them into cells on a specific worksheet. I also wrote a countA function that allows me to write to a new row every time I hit the input button. For a reason that I cannot understand, it will only write to the active worksheet no matter what sheet I reference. Please Help!

```
Private Sub inputlight_Click()

Dim emptyrow As Long

'Find the first empty row after row 47 on sheet "T5 Input Sheet"

emptyrow = 47 + WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("T5 Input Sheet").Range("b48:b219")) + 1

'transfer data

    Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = esize.Value
    Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = etype.Value
    Cells(emptyrow, 4).Value = ewatt.Value
    Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = elamps.Value
    Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = eusage.Value
    Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = efixtures.Value

End Sub
```

I've tried changing it to CountA(Worksheets("T5 Input Sheet"), (Sheets(2)), (Sheets("Sheet2") etc. but none of them print to anything but the active cell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to qualify `Cells`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take the correct approach using the `CountA` function however you also need to qualify your cells in order to stick values to a specific sheet.

```
Private Sub inputlight_Click()

    Dim emptyrow As Long

    'Find the first empty row after row 47 on sheet "T5 Input Sheet"
    emptyrow = 47 + WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("T5 Input Sheet").Range("b48:b219")) + 1

    'transfer data
    With Sheets("SHEET_NAME")

        .Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = esize.Value
        .Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = etype.Value
        .Cells(emptyrow, 4).Value = ewatt.Value
        .Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = elamps.Value
        .Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = eusage.Value
        .Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = efixtures.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

So where it says `SHEET_NAME` that's where you stick the destination Sheet name.

Comment: Nevermind I had forgotten the period in .Cells; Thank you so much for answering my question!